# How to dynamically change locale in uploadcare widget in angularjs based project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, locale, uploadcare

I am using [uploadcare widget](http://uploadcare.com) in my angularjs-based application. I integrated this widget as angular directive.

Documentation said, that I should set global variable to change locale:

```
<script>
    UPLOADCARE_LOCALE = 'ru';
</script>
```

But I am not very familiar with angular. So, I have no idea how do it dynamically.

I'll be glad of any help.

**Update**

---

I tryed to add **$rootScope** to my uploadcare directive and set **UPLOADCARE_LOCALE** variable there:

```
angular.module("project").directive 'projectUploadcare', ($uploadcare, $rootScope) ->
   restrict: 'E'
   replace: true
   template: '''
                <span>
                   <span class="uploadcare-preview"></span>
                   <input type="hidden">
                </span>
             '''
   link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      $rootScope.UPLOADCARE_LOCALE = 'ru'
      ... other code ...
```

but it does not help.

Comment: Just to clarify - is your goal to change locale in front-end on-the-fly, without reloading the page?

Comment: @DavidAvs Exactly! I'm sorry, if my explanation was not very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All global settings are read one time at page loading. [Locale](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/widget/#UPLOADCARE_LIVE) is global setting and can't be overwritten for particular widget. But [according to source](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-widget/blob/v1.3.1/app/assets/javascripts/uploadcare/locale.js.coffee#L34) there is a hack which allows one to rebuild translation at runtime.

First, you need to acquire internal Uploadcare API.

```
var internalUploadcare;
uploadcare.plugin(function(internal) {
  internalUploadcare = internal;
});
```

Then you can use internal `internalUploadcare.locale.rebuild` method to rebuild locale settings. Third step is reinitialize your existing widgets on the page. For example:

```
$('#uploader').html(
  $('#uploader input:eq(0)')
);
uploadcare.initialize($('#uploader'));
```

Add all together: http://jsbin.com/comone/1/watch

Answer (score 0):

by manual you should use

```
UPLOADCARE_LOCALE_TRANSLATIONS = {
  errors: {
    'portrait': 'Landscape images only'  // message for widget
  },
  dialog: {tabs: {preview: {error: {
    'portrait': {  // messages for dialog's error page
      title: 'No portrait images are allowed.',
      text: 'We are sorry but image should be landscape.',
      back: 'Back'
    }
  } } } }
};
```

and yes:

```
UPLOADCARE_LOCALE = 'en';
```

just be sure that you set this variable **BEFORE**.

but it's nothing to do with AngularJS

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. I don't want to make customization of locale. I just want to change it inside my app (from "en" to "ru", for example).

Comment: so try the second part of my answer